# python regex for multiple search patterns with alternation not working

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to fetch the number from below texts

```
text = 'was the 3001st most popular'
text1 = 'was the 2733rd most popular'
text3 = 'was the 3072nd most popular'
text4 = 'was the 4747th most popular'
```

I want it to return the numbers as in `3001, 2733, 3072, 4747` respectively from each line

i am using below

```
r = re.search('was the (.*)nd|was the (.*)st|was the (.*)rd|was the (.*)th', text).groups()
reg = next((item for item in r if item is not None), 'Not-Found')
```

But it's producing `4747th mo, 3001st mo etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify you pattern to look for digits (`\d+`) followed by either of `st`, `rd`, `nd`, `th`:

```
texts = [text, text1, text3, text4]

for t in texts:
    r = re.search("(\d+)(st|rd|nd|th)", t).group(1)
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
3001
2733
3072
4747
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also match only the digits:

```
\b\d+(?=st|[nr]d|th)
```

- `\b` As word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `st|[nr]d|th` Match either `st` `nd` `rd` `th`
- `)` Close the lookahead

If you also want to add a word boundary after the alternatives:

```
\b\d+(?=(?:st|[nr]d|th)\b)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/swzSVY/1).

```
import re

items = [
    "was the 3001st most popular",
    "was the 2733rd most popular",
    "was the 3072nd most popular",
    "was the 4747th most popular",
]
pattern = r"\b\d+(?=st|[nr]d|th)"

for item in items:
    m = re.search(pattern, item)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output

```
3001
2733
3072
4747
```